# deploying django app with heroku: "remote:! No such app"

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my django app with Heroku.
It creates the project when I do `heroku create` command, but it says 'no such app found' when i try to push to heroku.

I have all the required files such as Procfile and `requirements.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you `heroku create` and `heroku git push branch name`. The reason is Heroku relies on a git repository, so ensure you are in a repository you want to deploy to heroku before you run the above commands. Refer to this article [Deploying to heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python)